# How to tell the parser where to look for a local copy of xml.xsd?

Tags: xsd, eclipse-rcp

I am creating an eclipse rcp application in which I am using SAXParser to parse an XML document. The "EventsDefinition.xsd" which I am using to validate the XML document has following import:

`<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>`

I keep the "EventsDefinition.xsd" & "xml.xsd" in the eclipse folder of the exported rcp product.

For accessing the "EventsDefinition.xsd", I use the following code which works.

`URL fileURL = new URL(Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL() + "EventsDefinition.xsd");`

`File eventsDefinitionFile = new File(fileURL.getPath());`

`parser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", eventsDefinitionFile);`

With this, the parser is able to access "EventsDefinition.xsd" but not the "xml.xsd" referenced by it, because it tries to find the xml.xsd relative to the directory from which the rcp application is executed.

Is there a similar way to tell the parser to find the "xml.xsd" at eclipse folder rather than in the present working directory?

I tried specifying schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" in EventsDefinition.xsd, but it fails to read the schema. So I have to use the local copy of "xml.xsd" present at the exported product's eclipse folder.

Any suggestions will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with the import declaration. First, although permitted, is not recommended to use "namespace" as a namespace prefix. Second, the problem arises form the fact that you use "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" as namespace name, which is prohibited. Take a look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-prefix , precisely here:

> The prefix xml is by definition bound to the namespace name http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace. It MAY, but need not, be declared, and MUST NOT be bound to any other namespace name. Other prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this namespace name, and it MUST NOT be declared as the default namespace.

Try to rename the namespace name to something else (and the namespace prefix too). Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried after renaming the namespace name & namespace prefix both, but it doesn't work.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have to use a local copy of "xml.xsd" present at the eclipse folder of my rcp application. It works when the application is executed from eclipse folder where xml.xsd file is present, but when I execute it from some other directory, its not able to find the relative location of xml.xsd.                 I just need to find a way to inform the parser where to look for the "xml.xsd" referenced by my EventsDefinition.xsd.